# Absolute URL fails in Symfony2 WebCaseTest

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

The following code always results in no Route found. But the Route does exist.

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request(
   'GET', 
   '/app_dev.php/admin/', 
   array(), 
   array(), 
   array("HTTP_HOST" => "dev.example:8080"));
```

But always fails. If I go to http://dev.example:8080/app_dev.php/admin/ in my browser then it works fine.

Its like PHPUnit cannot **see** that host?

Comment: Have you tried without HTTP_HOST setted? I'm not sure you need it as you're running the command from Symfony2 project dir

Comment: Without `HTTP_HOST` it just uses localhost

Comment: What's returned error?

Comment: `No route found for "GET /app_dev.php/admin/"`

Comment: `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/');`

Comment: I think it's not possible to access absolute urls. In your code, you set http header only.

Comment: How can I change the host then? Because it's using localhost otherwise. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$crawler->request()` should not receive an actual URI, but the part after the front controller. So in your case, use:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request(
   'GET', 
   '/admin/', 
   array(), 
   array(), 
   array("HTTP_HOST" => "dev.example:8080"));
```

The reason behind this is that the client doesn't actually request for a page (to a host). It just simulates a request, by creating a `Request` object, passing it to the `AppKernel` and then parsing the `Response`. This is much faster.

If you want to test using a real request, I recommend installing and using [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/) or [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte).

Comment: That seems to have worked. I am sure I tried this though. Now to the next issue. Its completely ignoring my custom headers. `"HTTP_X-Token" => "an78f"`